# Make EhCache part of Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

Is it possible to make operations on `EhCache` make part of `Spring's` `JpaTransactionManager`?

During the transaction I'm doing some operations (put/evict) on `EhCache` and I want them to be committed when transaction succeeds and rollbacked when transaction fails. Just like the regular behavior on a database transaction.

How can I achieve this using `Spring` and `Hibernate`?
Do I need a `JTA transaction manager` for this?

Comment: EHCACHE automatically detects [common JTA transaction managers](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.1/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-tx_transaction_managers.html%23) at runtime. If using an unsupported or non-JTA transaction manager, just follow the instructions in the linked document to configure the transaction manager.

Comment: Please add the Ehcache version, the answer partially depends on that.